# Hardware requirements for a SharePoint 2013 Production environment

Tags: 2013, performance, hardware

I'm having trouble finding some concrete information on what the minimum hardware requirements are for a production SharePoint 2013 environment.  I'm talking number of servers in the farm.

I see the [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.15).aspx)  but the details are skewed to me.  It says

> Web server or application server in a three-tier farm Pilot, user
> acceptance test, or production deployment of SharePoint Server 2013 or
> SharePoint Foundation 2013. 12 GB 64-bit, 4 cores 80 GB for system
> drive

Well, that's IF I have a 3 tiered environment.  What if I have a 2 tiered environment?

Common sense would tell me that if I am running a heavy amount of services and a large user base, I should consider upgrading to a 3 tier.  However, I have a customer who is arguing with me saying that performance is not "optimal" and that Microsoft technically supports a 2 tier environment so it should be fast. Is there somewhere where Microsoft definitively says "You must have 3 servers in a production environment"?  Or how can I tell a customer that they need a 3rd server without so much push back on it?

Comment: Have you seen this thread http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28275/how-many-servers-with-what-kind-of-hardware-do-i-need

Comment: Looks like he is saying that 1 web server is sufficient for 10,000 users?  That doesn't seem right.  I've seen all the technet articles.  It's very open ended.  Is there something that outlines the recommended topologies given a specific scenario?  (ex: Production environment, 5000 users, search, UPS, 3 site collections, 1 web app, needs 3 servers load balanced...) or something along those lines?... that comes from Microsoft

Comment: No there is only the technet you have already found. Other than that is it trial and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following excerpt describes official Microsoft recommendation for 3-tier:

> This architecture introduces the breakdown of the topology into three
>   tiers:(...) A medium farm deployment is useful to serve environments
>   that have the following:
>
> - Several service applications distributed across multiple servers. A    typical set of features might include the Office Web Apps Service,
>     User Profile Service, Managed Metadata Service, and Excel Calculation 
>     Service.
> - **A user base of tens of thousands of users and a load of 10 to 50    requests per second.**
> - A data store of one or two terabytes.

They also write that:

> A small farm [two-tier] is useful to serve only limited deployments,
>   with a minimal set of service applications enabled, a relatively small
>   user base, a relatively low usage load (a few requests per minute up
>   to very few requests per second), and a relatively small volume of
>   data (10 or more gigabytes).

It all comes from here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758647(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I guess that will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly depend upon on the usage of the SharePoint.

- Total Number of User, Unique Users and Active User per day
- How many request per day
- How many Web Applications
- How much the Content , Number Of items (Document)
- how much crawl items?
- Upload Limit
- what kind of Service Application, Search, UPA, MMS, Excel etc?
- Fault Tolerance( 100% up time).

If you get the above answer then you can easily get which tier is good for you. It is highly recommended setup a stage farm and test it.

You can also check the Streamline Topology from MSFT which will give you more information.

[Streamlined Topologies for SharePoint 2013](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=286957)

[Plan service deployment in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219591(v=office.15).aspx)

[Services on Server Install Worksheet for Streamlined Topologies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37001)